# How to unbind a live event?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to unbind the click event for my code.

I have

```
$('#test').unbind('click'); //this won't work

$('#test').live('click', function(e){
    alert('alert')
    $(this).unbind(e) //this won't work
})
```

I am using jquery 1.63 and I need `.live` for my element.

Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: sorry, but saying you *need* the `.live()` method gets an immediate -1 from me. `.delegate()` is preferred (v1.4.2). But upgrading your version of jQuery (to v1.7.2+) and using `.on()` is even more preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `die()` method.

Comment: Which is exactly what you would expect :)

Comment: There should be a `taxes()` method which monitors a `live` event :P ("There are only two things certain in life - death and taxes.")