# jQuery off() or bind() will not when using live

Tags: jquery

I'm at my wit's end with this problem

The idea here is to prevent a link from working until the script completes its work and enables the link again.

**I'm using live, and don't intend changing it.** The below script will work without live, but will not work with live. Can you see why?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.user').live('click',function() { // All works well if live is removed.
    //But I need live, since things change and there's a lot of old code using it.
        console.log('Invoked');
        // Do anything to disable the link
        $('.user').unbind('click'); // Does not work
        //$('.user').off('click'); // Does not work either

       //Once the script is done with its ajax work, enable it again
         //$('.user').bind('click');
        //$('.user').on('click');

    });

});


<div class="container">
    <div><i class="icon-add user"></i></div>
    <div><i class="icon-add user"></i></div>
    <div><i class="icon-add user"></i></div>
    <div><i class="icon-add user"></i></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The counterpart to `.live` is `.die`: http://api.jquery.com/die/. That said, you should not be using `.live` anymore. See http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to unbind a live event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596169/how-to-unbind-a-live-event)

Comment: So I use die('click')? How do I enable it again?

Comment: Any help on how I can get this working...

Comment: which jquery version are you using?????

Comment: @rajeshkakawat v1.8.3

Comment: You can get it working by not using `.live()` at all but switching to `.on()` and `.off()`, as has already been said. If you have 1.8.3 and use `.live()` it's *already* just an alias for `.on()`: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.8-stable/src/event.js#L955

Comment: @Juhana Even with on, I cannot figure how to disable the <i> once, then enable it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did u try use .one() ?

```
$('.user').one('click',function() { ...
```

Comment: The idea is to disable it while data is submitted and returned, and enable it again.

Comment: `$('.user').live('click',function() {
if($(this).attr('disabled')) return false;
//then add attr when data is submitted
$(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
// remove attr when data returned
$(this).removeAttr('disabled');`

Comment: No luck, comrade :-). I'm guessing disabled will not work with an `<i>`

Comment: It's in the question. That's all I have and I'm testing with. Except that now I added your code.

Comment: Your fiddle helped solve the problem. Thanks very much for that.

Answer (score -1):

`live()` function is deprecated from jQuery 1.7 : [have a look at this page](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

You should better use `on()` function : [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Not the downvoter, but this is a comment, not an answer to the question.

Comment: I don't think so : using a deprecated function and then have a weird or  broken behaviour is  normal : it's deprecated. And I quote the jQuery documentation : `Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().`.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments, `.live()` in 1.8.3 is an alias to `$( document ).on()` so just replacing it won't help.